# Switch 2 elements in a 2d vector algebraically

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, rotations

I'm new to lineair algebra so maybe I am asking a silly question here.

What I mean with the title is this command in Matlab/Octave:

```
v1 = [5 1]
sqrt(rotateVector(v1, [deg2rad(90)]).^2)
```

which results in [1 5]

I understand this to only work for an initial vector with positive values for its elements.

Is there a different way to switch the elements in a 2D vector algebraically, that could be explained by a geometric operation as well?

I was thinking of rotating v1 on a different axis in 3D, but that yielded a vector with twice the number of elements (4 in total).

The reason I am asking is because I would like to understand the dot product geometrically (for 2d vectors). And I am looking in to the relation with a parallelogram constructed by the 2 vectors, or the elements of the 2 vectors, summed separately.

Comment: Could always multiply by 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1  \\
1 & 0    \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit `v1 * [0 1; 1 0]` works indeed! Awesome. How would I imagine this rotation geometrically? I do not understand how to conceptually rotate on a 2D or 3D plane, based on the given matrix.

Comment: @MikedeKlerk, this is not a rotation, it is a reflection across line $x=y$. A rotation matrix requires determinant is 1. This matrix has a determinant of -1.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Is this called a Hadamard transform by the way?